# Return Value in column if two columns Contains Specific Text if specific text not found then copied into a different column

Tags: excel

I am working on a project to clean up an excel spreadsheet. I have two columns H & I that have doctor specialties. I need to run a search in these two columns and find the specific text "Internal medicine" if this value is found I need to copy that text into Column J if any other text is found in columns H&I that text needs to go into column K.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub copyif()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
  Set SrchRng = Range("h2:i2")
  For Each cel In SrchRng
  If Range("H2").Value = "Internal Medicine" And Range("I2").Value = "Internal Medicine" Then
  
End Sub
```

I don't know if I am starting this code correctly and can't figure out the copy portion of the code.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this using VBA? You can do it with worksheet functions and be done in under 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyif()
Dim Matriz As Variant
Dim i As Long

Matriz = Range("H2:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = LBound(Matriz) To UBound(Matriz) Step 1
    If Matriz(i, 1) = "Internal Medicine" And Matriz(i, 2) = "Internal Medicine" Then
        'value into column J
        Range("J" & i + 1).Value = "Internal Medicine"
    Else
        'concatenated valuea into colum K
        Range("K" & i + 1).Value = Matriz(i, 1) & " " & Matriz(i, 2)
    End If
Next

Erase Matriz
  
End Sub
```

It will check all cells from row 2 to last non empty cell in column I.

If **both** cells say `Internal Medicine`, ut will write `Internal Medicine` on column J. Any other case will concatenate the text of both cells and write it into column K

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. The formula I was able to use for Column J: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Internal medicine",H2&I2)),"Internal Medicine","") and for Column K: =SUBSTITUTE(PROPPER(H2&" " & I2),"internal medicine","").